# Displaying 2 metrics on a tableau map

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and I have requirements as below:

I need to create a dashboard with a filter on Paywave or EMV and show count of Confirmed and Probable on a geo map.

When I select EMV from the quick filter, it should show a count of confirm & probable for that city. I should be able to drill down and see a count of confirm and probable for zip codes as well.

I am not sure how to achieve the above requirements.

As shown  below I have fields like:

```
                                       EMV           Paywave
 mrchchant_city, mrch_zipcode  confirm  probable  confirm  probable 
      A            1001          10      15         20       18
      B            1005          34      67         78       12
      C            2001          24      56         76       45
      C            2001          46      19         63       25
```

Please let me know if any information required from my side.

Comment: what's the issue- Tableau isn't identifying your geo dimension?

Comment: Hi- Its identifying geo dimension but i need to show count of confirm and probable on the city names and also once i drill down from city to zipcode then also it should show count of both- I need a solution to achieve this.

Comment: ok,add some sample data or post your `.twbx` file that should be easy to check. and it looks straight forward,you got 3 things `1.geo dim` `2.some(Count  measure) ` `3.A filter/parameter to switch city<-> zipcode`

Comment: I am not sure how to add .twbx here,,,Can you please let me know wot to attach.do i need any points to attach?

Comment: umm.. [you could use this:](http://www.filedropper.com/)

Comment: This site is restricted by my company so cant drop the twbx.Do u have tableau account?

Answer (score 1):

This will be a lot easier on you if you restructure your data a bit. More often than not, the goal in Tableau is to provide an aggregated summary of the data, rather than showing each individual row. We'll want to group by dimensions (categorical data like "EMV"/"Paywave" or "Confirm"/"Probable"), so this data will be much easier to work with if we get those dimensions into their own columns.

Here's how I personally would go about structuring your table:

```
+----------------+--------------+---------+----------+-------+-----+
| mrchchant_city | mrch_zipcode | dim1    | dim2     | count | ... |
+----------------+--------------+---------+----------+-------+-----+
| A              | 1001         | Paywave | confirm  | 20    | ... |
| A              | 1001         | Paywave | probable | 18    | ... |
| A              | 1001         | EMV     | confirm  | 10    | ... |
| A              | 1001         | EMV     | probable | 15    | ... |
| B              | 1005         | Paywave | confirm  | 78    | ... |
| B              | 1005         | Paywave | probable | 12    | ... |
| B              | 1005         | EMV     | confirm  | 34    | ... |
| B              | 1005         | EMV     | probable | 67    | ... |
| C              | 2001         | Paywave | confirm  | 76    | ... |
| C              | 2001         | Paywave | probable | 45    | ... |
| C              | 2001         | EMV     | confirm  | 24    | ... |
| C              | 2001         | EMV     | probable | 56    | ... |
| C              | 2001         | Paywave | confirm  | 63    | ... |
| C              | 2001         | Paywave | probable | 25    | ... |
| C              | 2001         | EMV     | confirm  | 46    | ... |
| C              | 2001         | EMV     | probable | 19    | ... |
| ...            | ...          | ...     | ...      | ...   | ... |
+----------------+--------------+---------+----------+-------+-----+
```

(Sorry about the dim1 and dim2, I don't really know what those dimensions represent. You can/should obviously pick a more intuitive nomenclature.)

Once you have a table with columns for your categorical data, it will be simple to filter and group by those dimensions.